# Looking for Windows app/service to forward RSS feeds to email

Tags: windows, rss

I administer a wiki on a machine on our LAN with a private IP. This means that I can't subscribe to the RSS feeds from it with Google Reader as I do for all other RSS feeds. Up till now I have subscribed to these feeds in Outlook but our company mail is migrating to Google Mail and I will soon stop using Outlook.

I don't want to install a fully-fledged RSS reader just for the few feeds from the wiki and was wondering if there is some lightweight RSS forwarder app or service I can run on my workstation that can consume the feeds and forward posts to me as email messages.

Answer (score 2):

[RSS2Email](http://www.allthingsrss.com/rss2email/about/) (open source) sounds like what you're looking for.

Comment: Following the readme to set it up but it isn't working. The first time I try to run it with "r2e new ..." it throws an exception.

  File "rss2email.py", line 191
    except Exception, e:
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

and I don't know enough about Python to figure out what's wrong.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm no Python expert myself, but have you got Python 3 instead of Python 2?  The two aren't compatible which could lead to a syntax error.

Comment: Ah, that will be it. I just grabbed what looked like the latest version of Python; didn't realise they weren't compatible. Will get Python 2 on Monday and try again.